# Online php script runner

Tags: php

I want to develop an online PHP script runner. I don't know how get started with it.  Any basic ideas will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by an "online script runner"?  Like http://codepad.org/?

Comment: You'd either have to `eval` the code, or save it as a file, then `include` it (or run it via command line).

Comment: This is probably really a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501904/prevent-application-from-introducing-harmful-changes-on-the-server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very simple form:

```
eval($_GET["code"]);
```

but you have to pay attention to the security risks of doing so.
It is highly recommended to filter some "evil code" like create/delete files on the webspace etc.