# How to create write and run your php code online

Tags: php

Give me solution for this issue. I want to create a site : write and run your php code online as same as this site : http://www.writephponline.com/ (have a textarea, button run & output area). Please help me (I really don't know where start) because I am newbie

```css
.output {
    background: #eee;
    min-height:40px;
  }

textarea {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<textarea name="txtCode" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="run" name="btnRun"/>
<br/>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

Comment: There is huge security issues to handle as a 'newbie', I would recommand you something easier to do

Comment: thank you very much about your sharing. I only want debug at my website, it's not public

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Online php script runner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007427/online-php-script-runner)

Comment: @L. feir : thank you very much. I've understand use : eval method

Answer (score 4):

Honestly to say, if you are a newbie you'd better shouldn't write software like this, because it will result in a big security whole online and your server will be hacked soon after you will launch your website.

Comment: @TinhNQ you said 'site like this' so I thought it will be public. If this is for your local needs, read about this function first http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php  then maybe you will come up with deeper understanding of the problems you will face and re-think your tak

Answer (score 0):

You have many options if your are beginner and looking forward to learn try the "Try it" button for php at [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) otherwise you have tools like

1)[CodePen](http://codepen.io/)

2)[PHP Fidddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

3)[Codepad](http://codepad.org) (Works for some many languages including c++, java etc)

4)[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com) (Awesome)

5)[IDEone](https://ideone.com/)

if you do CSS which you can hardly do without check out [CSS Desk](http://cssdesk.com/) there's also [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) for JavaScript with some googling you will find more of them. Hope that helped.

Comment: thank you very much about your sharing. I only want debug at my website, it's not public

Comment: You are welcome if you just want to debug you website code then doing that online is insecure, so follow @Bogdan's advice. :)